# Can I overload method in module.export in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have an app.js with this code:

```
var addnote = (title,body) => { /* enter code here */ }
module.exports = {addnote};
```

Can I add another `addnotes` function with different parameters to that file?

Comment: It's unclear how it's used. Are you using addnote in same module (app.js)? Are you able to modify this module? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: It can be done using inheritence. For modules, you can instead have a different name or can handle different things in one function

Answer (score 1):

Function overloading in JavaScript does not exist like in other programming languages such as C# and Java.

What you should be looking to do is pass an object as a parameter that has properties attached and filter them out there..

You could call different functions from your little 'mapping function' just implement the logic there if it isn't big (to keep the code clear).

```
function foo(parameters){

   var title = parameters.title;
   var body = parameters.body;

   if(parameters.extraProperty){
      // oh we have extraProperty passed in too, run a different function?
      bar(title, body, parameters.extraProperty); // ??
   }
}

foo({title: 'Title', body: 'Body', extraProperty: 'This is extra...'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own custom module, you can use the concept of function overriding, where each child class can have its own way to handle something and also have a default way to do things.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  greet() {
    console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
  
  greet() {
    console.log(`Hey there ${this.name}. This is Child 1`);
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
  
  greet() {
    console.log(`Hi there ${this.name}. This is Child 2`);
  }
}

const o1 = new Child1('Foo')
const o2 = new Child2('Foo')

o1.greet();
o2.greet();
```

But if you are trying to override a function in an external module(*You do not have access to that code, like a library*), my suggestion is to create a wrapper and add functionality there.